How Detect Vehicle Parking for Android Auto App
I’m currently developing an Android Auto app, and I’m using the LongMessageTemplate to display content only when the vehicle is parked, as required by Android Auto guidelines. I Attached a image about it's docummentation

Here’s my problem: the LongMessageTemplate is not displaying correctly. It seems that the system is constantly detecting that the vehicle is in motion, even when the car is actually parked. As a result, the template content doesn’t show, and I suspect that it might be due to some validation or configuration issue.
Here’s what I’d like help with:

Is there a specific validation step or configuration I might be
missing that could prevent the system from correctly identifying the
vehicle's status?
Are there known limitations, bugs, or workarounds    related to
detecting whether the vehicle is parked?
How can I ensure    that the    LongMessageTemplate behaves as
expected and only displays    when the    vehicle is not moving?


Are you experiencing this in a real car? If so, the two main possibilities would be that the car is not correctly reporting driving state to Android Auto through the head unit, or there could be a bug in Android Auto or the Car App Library causing the driving state to be misrepresented.
This is because the app host (i.e. Android Auto) takes care of tracking the driving state and modifying the presentation of the LongMessageTemplate - there isn't anything you need to do as a developer to handle the state changes.
Can you replicate this issue using the Desktop Head Unit? https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/dhu#restrictions shows how to simulate driving state. That would narrow down whether this is an issue with the car or with Android Auto/the Car App Library.

Yeah, the problem is only seen in real cars, and they are from different makes and models. This problem does not happen when emulating from desktop head unit.

For any given (make, model, year) pair, is it happening on all of those cars? Or just a small percentage of them?

Hi Ben, sorry for delay, these days I have been playing with different vehicles and devices that add android auto functionality. But it seems that the issue is presented sometimes. So, I think that is due that the car is not correctly reporting driving state as you mentionated.
